# Extract Month from a Date and convert it to Month in words

Tags: r

I have obtained the date like obtaining this "2018-05-31". 
Now, I want to create a new columnn which would be the month extracted, 05, and converting it to words "May". How could I do it?

```
df$Fecha<-as.Date(df$Fecha)
df$Fecha
[1] "2020-02-01" "2020-01-01" "2020-02-01" "2020-02-01"

df$Mes <- df$Fecha(Month = format(as.Date(df$Fecha), '%b'))
df$Mes
```

I get an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `format` after converting to `Date` class.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Month = format(as.Date(str1), '%b'))
df1
#  Month
#1   May
```

---

If it is to create a new column in an already existing dataset

```
df$Mes <- format(as.Date(df$Fecha), '%b')
```

If we need the full name, change the `%b` to `%B`

#### data

```
str1 <- "2018-05-31"
```

Comment: Hi, I do not get it to work. I put the code in my original comment.

Comment: @LETIESPINAEZCURDIA What is the `df$Fecha(` doing in the code.  I used `data.frame(`. Here `data.frame` is a constructor function while your `df$Fecha` is a column in a dataset.  It doesn't act like a function `()`

Comment: So, the thing is that I want to create a new column in my dataframe extracting the month, rather than creating a new dataframe

Comment: @LETIESPINAEZCURDIA you can just do, `df$Mes <- format(as.Date(df$Fecha), '%b')`

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!!